# No compatible version found: @angular/router@^2.0.0-rc.4 error while installing angular2 RC4 router

Tags: angular, routes, npm, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I have package.json dependencies as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.1.15",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
```

But while npm install it gives following error:

```
G:\rc4>npm i
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"                                         npm ERR! node v6.0.0                                                            npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! No compatible version found: @angular/router@^2.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 3.0.0-beta.2, 3.0.0-beta.1, 3.0.0-alpha.8, 3.0.0-alpha.7, 3.0.0-alpha.6, 3.0.0-alpha.5, 3.0.0-alpha.4, 3.0.0-alpha.3, 3.0.0-alpha.2, 3.0.0-alpha.1, 3.0.0-alpha.0, 2.0.0-rc.2, 2.0.0-rc.1, 2.0.0-rc.0, 0.2.0, 0.1.0, 0.0.1, 0.0.0-7, 0.0.0-6, 0.0.0-5, 0.0.0-4, 0.0.0-3, 0.0.0-2, 0.0.0-1, 0.0.0-0
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     G:\rc4\npm-debug.log

G:\rc4>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`angular-router` has rc version till `3` like "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.3",

After that version they release angular/router seperately as a beta version like

`"@angular/router":"3.0.0-beta.2"`

Comment: So in with version is the redirectTo supported for routes-path? And how is possible to see tags with rc.5 on github? https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/2.0.0-rc.5/modules/%40angular/router

Comment: I don't understand what is your question exactly?

Comment: I just wanted to say that for router I still see tags in angular github repo like rc.4, rc.5 etc, but when I try to use them (because I need the `redirectTo` property witch is not supported in rc.1) the compiler complaines with "No compatible version" error.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent router version is `3.0.0-beta.2`

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I'm little bit confused I had already used router-rc2 but I can not see this version in the mentioned link